# Entity Framework select from link table with list

Tags: .net, entity-framework, select, linq-to-entities

Using the following database table structure:

**Order** Table:

```
OrderId
OrderName
```

**OrderItem** Table:

```
OrderId
ItemId
```

**Item** Table:

```
ItemId
ItemName
```

I have an 'Order' entity that has an 'Items' collection. What I need to do is return all orders that contain certain items. Example: All orders with items with id: 1, 4 and 5 (I don't care if it has other items as well). I currently have the selected id's in a List object (it doesn't have to be a list though). I have tried various ideas with 'contains' method but to no avail.

Because OrderItem is a link table, I can't access it as an entity itself. If I could then presumably I could do:

```
context.OrderItems.Where(m => selectedIds.Contains(m.ItemId))
```

or something like that.

Is there a way of doing this in a single query without having to loop around the results?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
context.Orders.Where(o => o.Items.Any(i => selectedIds.Contains(i.ItemId)))
```

This requires EF 4.